# MXML - Create combobox dynamically on click of button

Tags: apache-flex, dynamic, combobox, mxml

Need help on creating combo box dynamically in Flex. How do I create combobox dynamically on click of button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please include a sample of your code along with details of which part's giving you trouble?

Comment: I am new to flex and mxml. trying to develop small app. Looking for some examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
public function createComboBox_clickHandler(event:Event):void {
            var myComboBox:ComboBox = new ComboBox();
            var comboBoxDataProvider:ArrayCollection =new ArrayCollection([
                { name: "box1", value: "value1"},
                { name: "box2", value: "value2"},
                { name: "box3", value: "value3"},
                { name: "box4", value: "value4"}
            ]);

            myComboBox.x = 100;
            myComboBox.y = 100;
            myComboBox.dataProvider = comboBoxDataProvider;
            myComboBox.labelField = "name";
            myComboBox.addEventListener(ListEvent.CHANGE, myComboBox_ClickHandler);
            container.addElement(myComboBox);
        }

        public function myComboBox_ClickHandler(event:ListEvent):void{
            trace(event.currentTarget.selectedItem.value);
        }
```

And Button for the click (and a container for them both)

```
<s:BorderContainer id="container" width="100%" height="100%">
    <s:Button id="createComboBoxButton" click="createComboBox_clickHandler(event)" label="Create a combobox dynamically"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```